# How to trigger build task on saving specific files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Working on a language extension with tmLanguage.yaml would like it to process to tmLanguage.json on save, it runs when I press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`B` but sometimes I forget to press it.

FilePath: syntaxes/mylanguage.tmLanguage.yaml

tasks.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "npm",
            "script": "yaml2json",
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

package.json script definition

```
    "scripts": {
        "yaml2json": "npx js-yaml syntaxes/mylanguage.tmLanguage.yaml > syntaxes/mylanguage.tmLanguage.json"
    },
```

- Would be ideal if it could pass the first part of filename here as an argument for working with multiple inputs.